# CopyOnWriteArrayList vs AtomicArrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I know that CopyOnArrayList rather than locking the list, creates a seperate copies of the list for every modification and multiple threads do access it at the same time but still data consistency is maintained because of cloning, and AtomicArrays will use a lock, and only single thread can access it at a time.

So CopyOnArrayList will be helpful if we have more read operations.

Have I got it right till here and is there anymore to it?

Comment: This question is better suited for software engineering stack exchange

Comment: ... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Studying for an exam, so clearing the theoretical concepts